# Update data in php and Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I had a problem with this code!! I wrote it but in the run its tell that is undefined variable !! I did not know where is the error. Please help me.
for my knowledge it is already defined in the connection.php.
**updateform.php**

```
<?php
include "connection.php"; 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html> 
<head> 

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css"> 

    <title>Update menu</title> 

</head> 

<body> 
<h1>Update the menu!</h1>
<form method="POST" action="update.php">
<?php
$query="SELECT * from menu WHERE Item_id='$Item_id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $Item_id=$row[0];
    $Item_name=$row[1];
    $Price=$row[3];
    $Description=$row[2];



}

?>
<label style="color:white;">
<strong>Item name: </strong><br />
<input type="text" name="name" size="30" value="<?php echo $Item_name;?>"></label> <br />
<label style="color:white;">
<strong>Price: </strong><br />
<input type="text" name="Price" size="5" value="<?php echo $Price;?>"></label><br />

<label style="color:white;">
<strong>Item description: </strong><br />
<input name="Description" size="40" value="<?php echo $Description;?>"></label><br />



<input type="hidden" name="Item_id" size="5" value="<?php echo $Item_id;?>">

<input type="submit" value="Update" style="color:black; background-color:#f2f2f2;">
</form>


</body>
 </html>
```

**and The update.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Update menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("project",$conn);
$query="UPDATE menu SET Item_name='".$_POST['Item_name']."',Description='".$_POST['Description']."',Price='".$_POST['Price']."'WHERE Item_id='$id'";
//echo query
$result=mysql_query($query,$conn);
mysql_close($conn);
header("Location:http://localhost/project/aindex.php");
exit();


?>


</body>
</html>
```

the output:
[here is the error!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRqyw.png)

Comment: 1. Post the error verbatim. 2. Learn PDO :)

Comment: @AshMenhennett I post the error . It is work with me with simple MySQL.

Comment: Declare the variables shown in error before the while loop. Set initial values, ```null``` would be ok.

Comment: @AshMenhennett Thank you so much it works now. I  want to ask you another question please.

Comment: @AshMenhennett in the Update.php, all the post works except Item name I did not know why!!

Comment: @AshMenhennett when I add a value it is return null (no variable).

Comment: Should be ```$_POST['name']``` in SQL ```update``` statement.

Comment: @AshMenhennett I really appreciate your help. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables shown in error before the while loop.